# Prevent <span> tags from becoming tabs when selecting text

Tags: css, html, whitespace, removing-whitespace

So, I have an old website that uses html tables extensively.
In the table cells, there's usually a `<span>` tag with a few attributes on it. I cannot change the structure of those tables.
When someone wants to select all the text in a cell, if they don't make absolutely sure to only select the visible characters, the `<span>` tag that contains the text is converted into a tab character. So if they paste the text somewhere it will start with a tab.

Example:

```css
table {
  margin-left: 230px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
p, textarea {
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table><!-- (comments to remove whitespace between tags)
  --><tbody><!--
    --><tr><!--
      --><td><span>first cell</span></td><!--
      --><td><span>hi there</span></td><!--
    --></tr><!--
  --></tbody><!--
--></table>
<p>Select "hi there" from the end to the begginning, by going past it, and paste it below, you will see a tab character at the beginning.<br>
(There can also be a new-line character before "first cell")</p>
<textarea></textarea>
```

**Basically what I want is that the text that actually gets copied is exactly the text that is visually highlighted**. At least if the selection is inside a single cell.
Is it possible to do this with css?

Again, I can't change the HTML structure, only the css, so I can't replace those `<span>`s with some other HTML tag.
Also, I can't use Javascript to do things like "transforming" the cells into inputs when the user clicks on them so he can select the text precisely. Just in case someone would think about this solution (which would be cool, but I can't do it).

**Edit**: welp I found a reasonable solution shortly after posting the question (the rubber ducking worked with a delay...). The solution is to add a padding in the table cell. And the tab character doesn't even have anything to do with the `<span>`. It appears when your selection goes into another cell.
But still, I'd like to know if there's any way to remove this kind of whitespace with css.

Comment: It's solely up to a user to be careful with selecting text unless you want to add "Copy cell to clipboard" action on cell click.

Comment: Sorta. In my case it's my fault because there's no padding in the cells. Even just that helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
html{ 
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none; 
}
span,p,textarea,div,br,td{
    -o-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

you can add more tag names in list of span,p,div.....

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, the tab still appears. Please see my edit. It wasn't actually the `<span>` tag being converted into a tab, that tab is added by the browser because the selection goes into another cell. With that tab you can select an entire table's text and still have it somewhat formatted when you paste it somewhere.

Comment: ok.. do u cleared cache while testing with my solution ? add ?v=1.2.3 next to css file name... e.g. <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css?v=1.2.3"> and simply change 1.2.3 when you make changes in css file...

Comment: I tested it directly in the browser's console.